# ReferenceError: WebForm_AutoFocus is not defined

Tags: asp.net

I have my web application asp.net everything is working well but when i publish it from another computer to localhost it  throws an error

```
ReferenceError: WebForm_AutoFocus is not defined
```

and also `Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_FireDefaultButton is not defined`

in my code behind i have `textbox1.Focus()`

so what's the problem and how to  fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn off the ISAPI filters.

Comment: wait a second i will try

Comment: Christian Mark, doesn't help

Comment: In the IIS of the computer where you publish the website?

Comment: Wait, have you checked your usings?

Comment: Christian Mark,No i am afraid idon't know where  i can check my usings and what are they used for, so tell me please where and what to check and i'll do it

Comment: ooh sorry you mean using system; and so on?

Comment: ,`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`

Comment: so is it okay or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36076/discussion-between-user2114177-and-christian-mark)

Answer (score 2):

This happens also when **webresource.axd** file is inaccessible. Sometimes Firewall policy of Web Server can create this issue.

Please ensure this file is accessible.

If this file is accessible then look solutions provided in other answers of this question.

Comment: If your system is using Owin authentication, calls to WebResource.axd will fail until a user is logged in. To resolve this you can add the following to web.config:  <location path="WebResource.axd">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by
1) adding this to web config

```
< system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

2) Turning off isapi filters

3) changing iis aplication pool to 4.0 integrated

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and I found the real problem that caused it and the solution.

I have Global.asax file which works with `Session` object in `Application_AcquireRequestState` method. As it turned out `WebResource.axd` does not have `Session`, so I get "500 Internal Server Error" in `WebResource.axd` HTTP request. That's why my website was losing all ASP.NET service javascripts.

Solution: add `if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is IRequiresSessionState && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)` to the beginning of your Global.asax methods.